# Flutter Navigation2.0 with named route loading bar issue

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
ElevatedButton(
               onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(
                                    context, '/addFood'),
                                child: Text('I Have Food'))
```

The above navigation push causing the loading bar on the top. This caused after 2.5 flutter update!. Can't figure out how to resolve the issue.

PS : The loading bar appears to be new and whenever chrome loads the web page.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like found out the issue!.

When I introduce scaffold, the loading bar gone away, anyway flutter team should provide this new web page loading bar.

```
 MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
  theme: appTheme,
  home: SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
    body: BlocListener<AddfoodCubit, AddfoodState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        // TODO: implement listener
      },
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [**strong text**
```